# What is the best way to schedule task in android?

Tags: android, android-alarms

My project requirement is to schedule multiple tasks very frequently at exact time with delay between 0-5 seconds.
What is the best way to schedule tasks for this purpose? Below are the options I considered:
1. Alarm Manager : Using Alarm Manager I have observed alarm does not schedule below 5 seconds. Even if I am passing 3 seconds time, alarm broadcasts after 5 seconds.
Below is my code :

```
int requestCode = 101;
int delayTime = 3000L;

Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskBroadcastReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delayTime, pendingIntent);
```

2. Job Scheduler : I have read that this approach is not good for critical tasks and for exact time scheduling. And I need exact alarm scheduling for critical tasks.

Please point out other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is using Handler. And schedule tasks using postAtTime(Runnable r, long uptimeMillis) method.

For more info see : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html